# How do I increment CSS Y position coordinates using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating an animation that changes the value of a background image. It is working perfectly if I hard code in the coordinates, but I am trying to modify it so that it simnply increments the position by 20px.

Here's the code I am using to retrieve the original Y position - works perfectly:

```
$('.rss,.twitter,.jquery').each(function(){
// Returns "##px" and "##px"
var backgroundPositions = $(this).css('background-position').split(" ");
// Retrieve the original Y position
$(this).data("originalYpos", backgroundPositions[1].slice(0, -2));
});
```

Now I am trying to increment the value of originalYpos by 20px but this isn't working:

```
var animateNum = function() {
$('.rss,.twitter,.jquery').animate({
var YPos = $(this).data('originalYpos')+20;
backgroundPosition:  0 + "px " +  YPos + "px"}, 400, "easeOutCirc");
};
```

I do believe it is because the declaration of var Ypos isn't allowed inside the .animate(), but I need to refer to $(this), meaning the value of each of the 3 individual selectors as they are being animated.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be like this:

```
var animateNum = function() {
$('.rss,.twitter,.jquery').animate({
  backgroundPosition:  $(this).data('originalYpos')+20 + "px"}, 400, "easeOutCirc");
};
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. Unfortunately I did have it that way before and it didn't work - it returns this error in Firebug: "missing : after property id". My interpretation is that the declaration is not allowed inside .animate() (it is expecting a property).

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
var animateNum = function() {
   $('.rss,.twitter,.jquery').animate({
      backgroundPosition:  "0 " +  ($(this).data('originalYpos')+20) + "px"
   }, 400, "easeOutCirc");
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the response - unfortunately this doesn't work - I receive a "missing: after property id" error in Firebug. As background image animations aren't natively supported, I am using the "Background-Position Animations" plugin found here: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/backgroundPosition-Effect It seems to me that it is only expecting a property in the .animate(). I just need a way to make the position coords an incremental variable that can be read inside the .animate() functiion.

Answer (score 1):

Why store the old value at all:

From http://api.jquery.com/animate/

> Animated properties can also be relative. If a value is supplied with a leading += or -= sequence of characters, then the target value is computed by adding or subtracting the given number from the current value of the property.

So, the code below *should* work (although I haven't tried it myself)

```
var animateNum = function() {
   $('.rss,.twitter,.jquery').animate({
      backgroundPosition:  "+=20px"
   }, 400, "easeOutCirc");
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the response - unfortunately this doesn't work - I receive a "missing: after property id" error in Firebug. As background image animations aren't natively supported, I am using the "Background-Position Animations" plugin found here: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/backgroundPosition-Effect It seems to me that it is only expecting a property in the .animate(). I just need a way to make the position coords an incremental variable that can be read inside the .animate() functiion.